# Как узнать модель процесора, или видео карты, или количество ОЗУ через JS

Tags: javascript

в неравной борьбе с мультиаккаунтами на своем сайте встал остро вопрос, как быть, смс шлюза настолько дорогие что в день тратится до тысячи рублей, а профита нет, решил делать модуль сбора информации о пользователя для дальнейшего сравнения и вычисления мультиаккаунтов.

Из этого вытекает логический вопрос, что можно вытянуть с браузера юзера, название браузера, ос, размер экрана, разрядность ос уже есть, вопрос можно ли узнать как то процессор или рам или видеокарту?

Comment: а зачем заводить мультиаккаунт на твоем сайте?

Comment: ну например на сайте роздается бонус новичкам, или конкурс рефералов, или бонус за реферала... Есть море причин почему мультики не нужны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точное количество оперативки - никак, но `navigator.deviceMemory` - дает примерный размер ОЗУ в ГБ, возвращая одно из этих чисел: `0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8` (всё, что больше 8 - будет 8).

```js
console.log(navigator.deviceMemory);

console.log("Оттуда можно достать еще кое-какие данные для анализа:\n", navigator);
```

По видеокарте (нагло скопировано [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267764/how-to-get-the-video-card-driver-name-using-javascript-browser-side)):

```js
console.log(getVideoCardInfo());

function getVideoCardInfo() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  
  if (!gl) return { error: "no webgl" };
  
  const debugInfo = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
  
  return debugInfo ? {
    vendor: gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL),
    renderer: gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL),
  } : {
    error: "no WEBGL_debug_renderer_info",
  };
}
```

Можно еще посмотреть, что у него там хранится `console.log(localStorage);` - вдруг повезет поймать совпадения.

Comment: navigator.deviceMemory: [A floating point number; one of 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory) - это не совсем озу в гб

Comment: @Grundy, как же хорошо что ты есть 

Comment: У меня 4 плашки DDR5 по 16гб, но он пишет - 8ГБ :(